# How to convert timestamps within a R dataframe to date

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a R data frame with multiple columns with one of which containing a timestamp.

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1:4), timestamp=c(123513,2,3,4))
```

The problem I have is trying to convert the timestamp say 123513 (integer) into a date ("1970-01-02").

I have a function as below, that I wish to apply to all timestamps.

```
timestamp_to_date <- function(timestamp) {
    return (as.Date(as.POSIXct(timestamp, origin="1970-01-01", tz="Australia/Melbourne")))
}
```

Comment: Look at the `apply()` functions

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. After that please edit your question, put in data to play with!

Comment: both `as.Date` and `as.POSIXct` are vectorised so you can "apply" your function directly on a vector. Could you be more precise on the "does not work" part ? do you get an error message ? Please, also provide a sample of your `df`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other have mentioned, this should just work:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1:4), timestamp=c(123513,2,3,4))

timestamp_to_date <- function(timestamp) {
  return (as.Date(as.POSIXct(timestamp, origin="1970-01-01", tz="Australia/Melbourne")))
}

df$timestamp = timestamp_to_date(df$timestamp)

> df
  id  timestamp
1  1 1970-01-02
2  2 1970-01-01
3  3 1970-01-01
4  4 1970-01-01
```